# openlayers 3 with mapproxy Black area inside map

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, mapnik

I have a problem when use Ol3 with Mapproxy and Mapnik to get the layers from OSM database.
when I convert my work from Ol2 to Ol3 I see something wrong when I zoom in/out in map I get some black area and Thank you for help :)

This is my code to show the map

```js
map = new ol.Map({
            loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
            loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
            target : "map",
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                    })
            }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
            view: new ol.View({
               projection: "EPSG:4326",
               center: myLatLng,
               zoom : 6
            }),
            overlays: [overlay],
            layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
                                    title: "base Layer",
                                    type: 'base',
                                    visible: true,
                                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                                      projection: "EPSG:4326",
                                      url: 'http://localhost:8080/service?',
                                      params: {
                                        'LAYERS': "baseLayer"
                                      }
                                    })
                                  })
            ]
        });
```

Some image from my problem this map for Iraq

[image]

Comment: Please try to provide more information. Is it always the same tile(s)? Does reloading solve the problem? Is there any corresponding information in the log files?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of

```
'LAYERS'
```

use

```
LAYERS
```

(no quotes) in the params.

In my case I also modified the projection value.